# people picker and rich text box field not function well under presave. alert box pops up even there is info provided

Tags: jquery, people-picker

```
function PreSaveAction(){
var ITOwnerField = $("#ctl00_ctl41_g_648c8386_16ca_4729_9c59_c9757150bafe_ff41_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv");

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', ValidateUser);
function ValidateUser(){
var pickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='<Field Name>']");
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
var theUser = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
if (theUser.length != 0) {
alert("User is Valid");
}
else{
alert("User is Invalid");
}
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Please always ask the question with proper information. So community members can help you to provide the resolution.

Comment: Why wasn't this closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For People picker field you have to get the html element using below snippet

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', ValidateUser);
    return true;
}


function ValidateUser(){
    var pickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='<Field Name>']");
    var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
    var theUser = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    if (theUser.length != 0) {
    alert("User is Valid");
    }
    else{
    alert("User is Invalid");
    }
}
```

Replace `<Field Name>` token with the **Display name** of your people picker field in the above code.

For Rich text box field you may use this piece of code,

```
var richtextvalue = $('td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "<Rich Text Field Name>"; }).parent().parent().parent().find("div.ms-inputBox div.ms-rtestate-write").text();
if(richtextvalue.length-1!=0){
alert("The text box contains value");
}
```

These two scripts were working fine for me in presaveaction() method for me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41610/discussion-on-answer-by-nagarajan-muthukumar-people-picker-and-rich-text-box-fie).

Answer (score 1):

For a people selector, try something like`$("input[id^='YourPeoplePicker']").val()`

For a RTE, try something like `var comments = $("div[id^='Richtextfield'].ms-rtestate-write").html().length;`

You really need to start leveraging the dev tools of your browser and use the jQuery help documentation, it is really helpful.

Comment: how should i relate it using id of my field??

Comment: what is 'YourPeoplePicker' in code?

Comment: i tried ur People picker code on IE console and it gave undefined as output

Comment: The id of your people picker field when viewed in the dev tools, ^= is begins with.